# How do I get the serialized inventory item by the inventory id in NetSuite api with PHP?

Tags: php, api, netsuite

Here is the situation, I'm trying to get the Serialized Inventory Item based on the id (https://xxx.app.netsuite.com/app/common/item/item.nl?id=522216), however, when I tried the following code:

```
       $search = new TransactionSearchBasic();
      
       $type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
       $type->operator = 'anyOf';
       $type->searchValue = array('serializedInventoryItem');
       $search->type = $type;   

       $invetoryRef = new RecordRef();
       $invetoryRef->internalId = '522216';

       $params = new SearchMultiSelectField();
       $params->operator = 'anyOf';
       $params->searchValue = array($invetoryRef);
       $search->serializedInventoryItem = $params;

       $request = new SearchRequest();
       $request->searchRecord = $search;

      $searchResponse = $service->search($request);
```

However, the response that I'm getting the following error:

The field type's enum value  is invalid for this search.

Why would I be getting that error message?

Thank you,

Kevin Davis

Comment: Serialized Inventory Item is a different record type than Inventory Item. Searching for the latter won't bring up the former. Item is the base type of a whole pile of more specific types.

Comment: InternalId for the record type is `serializedinventoryitem`.